# Heroku Naked Domains and Google Indexing?

Tags: heroku, seo

I have a domain (www.wozzoncornwall.co.uk) set up and followed Heroku's recommendation not to use a naked domain. I've noticed the site seems to be taking an unusually long time to be indexed by google.....i'm not talking keywords, just searching the site name or domain. I previously had a holding page up for 3-4 months and this was indexed, however, I noticed that when I moved the app to Heroku this was clicking through to the URL without the www, so returning site not found. This isn't even in the index any more, google clearly dropped it due to 'site not found' but i'm concerned this is having an effect on the proper site being indexed. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use rack-rewrite (assuming Ruby app) to redirect your naked domain to the www (with a true 301 redirect) - but publish/advertise the www entry. You would need to add the naked domain to your application domains and the IP addresses - this is acceptable for simply redirection.

This should transfer the link juice from the none www to the www. If you use Google webmaster tools you can go into the settings and update them of the address change.

Comment: Yep, Ruby app. Not sure I fully understand what you're suggesting, but i'll take a closer look. Many Thanks.